# Command working in shell but not in script

Tags: shell-script, debian, shell

I have this git script, which gives me the output i need for a python program i'm using it in. The problem is, the script doesn't work on the Debian 7 Machine, where i need to use it on. It does however work without a problem on my Manjaro PC.

```
#!/bin/bash

branch=$1

if [[ -n "$branch" ]]; then

format=Author:%x09%an
format+=%x0aDate:%x09%ad
format+=%x0aRefs:%x09%d
format+=%x0a%x0a'%w(,4)%s'
format+=%x0a%x0a'%w(,4,4)%b'
git rev-list --pretty="$format" $branch
else
    echo "argument error"
fi
```

When i type the commands by myself it's also working.

Can somebody help me with this?

Edit:
The first error i get is about the 2 [[. If i change it to `if [ -n "$branch" ];` then it proceeds to the format declarations, where i get a "no found" error on every line. The git rev-list command however works but fails due to no argument.

Edit 2: Executing the script through `bash [script]` instead of `sh [script]` solved the problem! I'm still wondering though why it worked on my Manajaro machine with `sh`.

Comment: What about it is not working?  Do you get an error of any sort?  Please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/337624/edit) your question to include what happens and what you expect to happen instead

Comment: Sorry, just added the Error.

Comment: There's a space before the `#!` on the very first line. That's an error.

Comment: @Kusalananda, then he should have gotten something like a bad interpreter error.  It's OK to have a space there, or a space between the # and the ! or between the #! and the /.  Try it on a working bash script.

Comment: The first line was just bad formatting and is not in the actual script.

Comment: @airhuff With a space as first character, the script will be executed by whatever shell he's using interactively (and that shell might not understand `[[..]]` or `+=`). Likewise if there's a space between `#` and `!`. The first two characters are the "[magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Magic_number)" and they need to be exactly `#!`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, great clarification.  I've definitely misunderstood how that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sh` shell on your Manjaro installation may be `dash`, which does not understand the `[[ ... ]]` syntax, nor does it understand the `+=` syntax used to append to the value of a variable.

This would explain why those particular lines in the script fails to execute properly when the script is run with `sh` rather than with `bash`.

To alleviate this, make sure that the hash-bang line (`#!`) points to the correct path of `bash`, and make the script executable with `chmod +x scriptname.sh`.  This way you may run the script with e.g. `./scriptname.sh` without having to explicitly tell it to use `bash`.